# Why did the link to community elections disappear from the main page?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, design, election

Why did the link to community elections disappear from the main page but is is still on Meta?

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 for hand-drawn red circles, and because I wondered too.

Comment: We can put up a banner again manually, but I'm not sure if we should.

Comment: @Fabian Nah, just let it be. Status-bydesign. Here are some related meta posts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/111675/98786, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75832/98786, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77582/98786

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system messages are always time-limited, even for elections. The exception is the election notice on meta, which doesn't decay.

There will be a new automatic system message in addition to the notification every eligible voter gets once the election itself starts.

Answer (score 1):

While everything already said has been correct up to this point, we are in the process of rolling out a new community bulletin board feature for things that shouldn't be system messages anyway.  Since Skeptics is currently having an election, it's been enabled here early during the rollout.

For more information about the community bulletin board, please read [Nailing it up on your community bulletin board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board).

Comment: Was the removal of the banner from meta intentional?